# How to make the orderby dynamic with the model data

Tags: entity-framework

```cs
var baseQuery = _dbContext.tablename.AsQueryable();

var AllSales = await (
    from obj in baseQuery
    select new model()
    {
        column1= obj.column1,
        column1= obj.column1,
        
    }
    ).OrderBy().Skip(model.Start).Take(model.Length).ToListAsync();
```

I tried to add orderbydynamic function in place of orderby but it says this IQueryable does not contain the definition of orderbydynamic i want to add order by within model columns please suggest and thank in advance